# node net.createServer get connection path

Tags: node.js, sockets

Trying to cluster Socket.io using net.createServer. All examples are using IP to split what connection goes to witch node. However I'm using 4 servers with a load balancer that points ip;s to the different servers.

So in node cluster I would like to use an unique id to point the connection to a specific cluster.
Figure that each user that wants to connect can add a parameter to the connection url ws://localhost/socket.io?id=xxyyzz

**How can I get the connection url in net.createServer**

todays code for ip:

```
  var server = net.createServer({ pauseOnConnect: true }, function(connection) {
    // We received a connection and need to pass it to the appropriate
    // worker. Get the worker for this connection's source IP and pass
    // it the connection.
    var remote = connection.remoteAddress;
    var local = connection.localAddress;

    var ip = (remote+local).match( /[0-9]+/g )[0].replace(/,/g, '');
    var wIndex = ip % num_processes;
    var worker = workers[wIndex];

    worker.send('sticky-session:connection', connection);
});
```

Comment: Seems to be something with pauseOnConnect: true that the data isn't accessible.